# Correct pattern for Regex.Split

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I'm receiving strings such as:

- ABC123456DEF
- 123456
- ABC123456
- 123456DEF

What I would like to do is split the numbers from the string so ideally the output for the above would be:

- 'ABC', '123456', 'DEF
- '123456'
- 'ABC', '123456'
- '123456', 'DEF'

Would someone please be able to advise the best way to handle this using Regex.Split?

Thank you.

Paul.

EDIT:

Being as I was marked down, I thought I better show what I have already. This only brings the alphanumeric's, not the numeric's:

```
string pattern = @"\d+";
string barcode = "ABC123456DEF";
string[] result = Regex.Split(barcode, pattern);
```

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: Sorry, C#. I'll amend the question.

Comment: Why don't you try matching instead of splitting? `[A-Z]+|[0-9]+`

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I would just match `([0-9]+)|([A-Z]+)`, no need for `Regex.Split` here

Comment: Current workings added as I was marked down for not showing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this:**

```
//Based on:

//.NET 4.5

//Program that uses Match, Regex: C#

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String subject = "ABC123456DEF\n123456\nABC123456\n123456DEF"
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)|([0-9]+)");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(subject))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex.Split is exactly what you should use here:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

string pattern = @"(\d+)";
string barcode = "ABC123456DEF";
string[] result = Regex.Split(barcode, pattern).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Regexp.match approach in the other answer is likely better, however if you absolutely have to use Regexp.split the following pattern should work;

```
(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])
```